# Help sorting XML Data in .NET (maybe with LINQ query?)

Tags: wpf, xml, vb.net, linq, sorting

I have this hierarchy of XML

```
  <Chapters>
   <Chapter @num="">
    <Section @letter="">
     <Heading @num="" />
    </Section>
   </Chapter>
  </Chapters>
```

**I need to do a sort so that all chapters are sequenced in ascending order, each section within that chapter is sequenced in ascending order, and each heading in that section is sorted...**

Doing the following yields the Chapters sorted properly, but obivously the child data isn't sorted:

```
Dim chapsorted = From c In root.Elements
                 Order By c.@num Ascending
                 Select c
```

From there I'm lost.   I tried this crazy thing to get the full results I want, but that didn't do me any good either:

```
Dim chapsorted = From c In root.Elements
             Order By c.@num Ascending
             Select (From sec In c.Elements Order By sec.@letter Where sec.Parent Is c Select
                    (From hed In sec.Elements Order By hed.@num Where hed.Parent Is sec)))
```

That did me no good either.

There has got to be a simple way of doing this.... :-)  Help will be greatly appreciate, I've been spinning my wheels for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with your first query.  Construct an `XElement` out of the resulting list of sorted nodes by copying the name and attributes from the original `XElement`, and then nest that structure:

```
Dim chapsorted = New XElement(root.Name, _
    root.Attributes, _
    From c In root.Elements _
    Order By c.@num Ascending _
    Select New XElement(c.Name, _
        c.Attributes, _
        From s In c.Elements _
        Order By s.@letter Ascending _
        Select New XElement(s.Name, _
            s.Attributes, _
            From h In s.Elements _
            Order By h.@num Ascending _
            Select h)))
```

If you were sorting by the same attribute at every level, you could do a recursive solution like this:

```
Private Function SortChildElements(ByVal element As XElement) As XElement
    Return New XElement( _
        element.Name, _
        element.Attributes, _
        element.Nodes.Where(Function(node) Not TypeOf node Is XElement), _
        From child In element.Elements _
        Order By child.@num Ascending _
        Select SortChildElements(child))
End Function
```